# List<List<double>> in Property Grid

Tags: c#, propertygrid, collectioneditor

How can I edit a `List<List<double>>` in `propertyGrid`?

I wan't to edit two dimensional arrays like this:

```
[[0.0,0.0],[1.0,0.0]]
```

Comment: You're not supposed to modify directly the instance, but return a value? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I removed the code, You are right it is no good.

Comment: You mean you want to be able to edit directly [[0.0,0.0],[1.0,0.0]] like it was a TextBox?

Comment: Or like a collection. Meanwhile i modified the type to `double[][]`. It looks fine now, only if it is empty i get `Constructor on type System.Double[] not found`.

Comment: Ok, I've initialised the variable, now it works perfectly.